# Dynamically creating react components that don't refresh the DOM on every change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm working on a React app where we are rendering an unknown number of form elements passed in from another application. I have code setup to pull in all possible components and dynamically render each with props when it's needed (below), but every time I make *any* change (i.e. entering text in a text field, clicking a checkbox, etc.), every form element is updated. I'm unsure how to get around this because the rendering is done inside a map function, and I can't get rid of the map function because we have no idea what or how many elements will be sent in to be rendered. I am using redux, so can't adequately use shouldComponentUpdate, but I have used the `{pure: true}` option in `connect`, with no luck. Any ideas on how to do this?

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    InputBox,
    RadioGroup,
    ComboBox,
    CheckboxGroup,
    DatePicker
} from './components';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import * as actions from 'redux/actions/actions';
import {convertToVariable} from 'components/Utility/utils'

const componentLookup = {
    "InputBox": InputBox,
    "RadioGroup": RadioGroup,
    "ComboBox": ComboBox,
    "CheckboxGroup": CheckboxGroup,
    "DateField": DatePicker
};

class FormPanel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.logData = this.logData.bind(this);
    }

    logData(eventValues) {
        this.props.updateDialogValues(eventValues);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.uiContent.map((element) => {
                    const Tag = componentLookup[element.type];
                    return (
                        <Tag
                            {...element.defaults}
                            onValueChange={this.logData}
                            key={element.defaults.label}
                            name={element.defaults.variable || convertToVariable(element.defaults.label)}
                        />
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        dialogValues: state.app.dialogValues,
        actionInfo: state.xyz.actionInfo,
        actionPayload: state.xyz.actionPayload
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        updateDialogValues: (dialogValues) => {
            dispatch(actions.updateDialogValues(dialogValues))
        }
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, undefined, {pure: true})(FormPanel)
```

Comment: Hi @samiampersand your all component pointing to same state in redux store ? can you give more details.

Comment: return entire state to the mapStateToProps. it will update the component , but this is a temporary solution not preferable, The solution may differ based on the situation.

Comment: I have two states in the store, but now that I look at it it seems like all the form elements (which are the ones reloading each time) do point to the same store.